# Fast TCP receive

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I'm working on a TCP client. but for some reason it is not fast enough **receiving** data. If the server sends a string (about 140 characters) every 50ms it works fine, but it I change it to 10ms (or lower) the Client doesn't display every string.
I tried the same with another TCP chat program, and there 1ms was no problem.
So it should be possible ;-)

Below my code:

```
Imports System.Net, System.Text
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Client
Dim t As New TcpClient
Private Sub Client_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Try
        t.Connect("127.0.0.1", "50020")
        If t.Connected Then
            t.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf doread, Nothing)
            login()
            StatusStrip1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Application.Restart()
    End Try
End Sub
Sub login()
    senddata("LOGIN|")
End Sub
Sub doread(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        If t.Connected = True Then
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(t.GetStream)
            Dim msg As String = sr.ReadLine()
            TextBox1.Text = (msg & vbCr & vbLf) & TextBox1.Text
            t.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf doread, Nothing)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Application.Restart()
    End Try
End Sub
Sub senddata(ByVal message As String)
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(t.GetStream) 'declare a new streamwriter
    sw.WriteLine(message) 'write the message
    sw.Flush()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Interesting, this is a new way of breaking TCP implementations that I have not seen before.

Comment: Added "VB.NET" to the tag :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might not be aware of the fact that TCP connections represent a stream of bytes. Messages/packets are not preserved. You might receive as little as one byte at a time.

You assume that you are receiving whole lines.

Also, this hybrid use of binary reads and `StreamReader` cannot work for many reasons. One of them is that `StreamReader` buffers internally. Each time you create a new one you throw buffer contents away.

Why are you checking `t.Connected` all the time? If `false`, you simply do nothing. This is worse than not checking at all. Don't blindly copy code from the web (I know that you copied this because this broken pattern is all over the web and nobody would normally think of doing this).

```
Application.Restart
```

??? That's not an appropriate error strategy. Better: Dispose of all resources and show a message box.

This is really, really broken. Unsalvagable. Need to rewrite.

Simply do this on a background thread:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(...);
while (true) {
 var line = sr.ReadLine();
 if (line == null) break;
 Invoke(new Action(() => TextBox1.Text += line));
}
```

Or anything equivalent.

Comment: Hi usr,
Thank you for your feedback. I will see if I can rewrite your code to VB.NET.
I'm new in the TCP world and yes I copied the code and in looked like it was working fine ;-)
Only not for the fast communication as you explain .

Comment: TCP is *very* hard, maybe you can use something higher level such as WCF or HTTP + protobuf.